# PySpark: Convert Date

Tags: date, pyspark

How can I convert this date to a date format such that I can eventually transform it into yyyy-MM-dd? Similar examples, [Convert string of format MMM d yyyy hh:mm AM/PM to date using Pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64773981/convert-string-of-format-mmm-d-yyyy-hhmm-am-pm-to-date-using-pyspark), could not solve it.

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(sc.parallelize([
            ['Wed Sep 30 21:06:00 1998'],
            ['Fri Apr  1 08:37:00 2022'],
            ]),
                           ['Date'])
```

```
+--------------------+
|                Date|
+--------------------+
|Wed Sep 30 21:06:...|
|Fri Apr  1 08:37:...|
+--------------------+
```

```
# fail
df.withColumn('Date', F.to_date(F.col('Date'), "DDD MMM dd hh:mm:ss yyyy")).show()
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using wrong symbols for Day-Of-Week and Hour - try this one:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import to_date

df = spark.createDataFrame([('Wed Sep 30 21:06:00 1998',), ('Fri Apr  1 08:37:00 2022',)], 'Date: string')
df.withColumn('Date', to_date('Date', "E MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy")).show()

+----------+
|      Date|
+----------+
|1998-09-30|
|2022-04-01|
+----------+
```

Comment: Thanks this works with Spark > 3.0; what about modern Spark?

Comment: You can set the Spark config `spark.conf.set("spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy","LEGACY")` to maintain compatibility with Spark < 3.0. Related topic - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62602720/string-to-date-migration-from-spark-2-0-to-3-0-gives-fail-to-recognize-eee-mmm