# How to convert a String column to Date column for a PySpark dataframe using strptime function?

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, strptime

I want to convert a string column to a date column for a pyspark dataframe as follows :

|Date|
+-------+---
|10-Nov-15|
|11-Oct-17|

I know strptime function would work, but unable to use it with PySpark dataframe.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert pyspark string to date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38080748/convert-pyspark-string-to-date-format)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `to_date` function.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
......

df = df.withColumn('Date', F.to_date(F.lpad('Date', 9, '0'), 'dd-MMM-yy'))
df.printSchema()
df.show(truncate=False)
```

Comment: Yeah, thank you. But I guess this would not work if input is as below. With only single date field. 
|6-Oct-17|

Comment: Thank you. I figured a different approach. Left padded 0 as below.


df['StartDate'] = df['StartDate'].astype(str).str.pad(2, side='left', fillchar='0')

Comment: Sorry, just saw your question. I've updated the answer to use ```lpad``` preprocessing for non-2-bit days.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use to_date , which is natively present in Pyspark

The key is to find the appropriate parsing patterns.

The available DateTime Patterns for Parsing can be found - https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-datetime-pattern.html

Furthermore to handle edge cases , like - `2-Feb-20` and `02-Feb-20` , you can set the `timeParserPolicy=LEGACY` as the above link is applicable for Spark 3.x , more info about this can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62602720/string-to-date-migration-from-spark-2-0-to-3-0-gives-fail-to-recognize-eee-mmm)

#### Data Preparation

```
d = {
        'date_col':['10-Oct-15', '11-Oct-17', '2-Feb-20', '02-Feb-20']
    }

sparkDF = sql.createDataFrame(pd.DataFrame(d))

sparkDF.show()
+---------+
| date_col|
+---------+
|10-Oct-15|
|11-Oct-17|
| 2-Feb-20|
|02-Feb-20|
+---------+

sparkDF.printSchema()

root
 |-- date_col: string (nullable = true)
```

#### To Date

```
sql.sql("set spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy=LEGACY")

sparkDF = sparkDF.withColumn('date_col_parsed',F.to_date(F.col('date_col'),'dd-MMM-yy'))

+---------+---------------+
| date_col|date_col_parsed|
+---------+---------------+
|10-Oct-15|     2015-10-10|
|11-Oct-17|     2017-10-11|
| 2-Feb-20|     2020-02-02|
|02-Feb-20|     2020-02-02|
+---------+---------------+

sparkDF.printSchema()

root
 |-- date_col: string (nullable = true)
 |-- date_col_parsed: date (nullable = true)
```

#### To Date - SparkSQL

```
sparkDF.registerTempTable("TB1")

sql.sql(
    """
    SELECT
         date_col
        ,TO_DATE(date_col,'dd-MMM-yy') as date_col_parsed
    FROM TB1
    """
).show()

+---------+---------------+
| date_col|date_col_parsed|
+---------+---------------+
|10-Oct-15|     2015-10-10|
|11-Oct-17|     2017-10-11|
| 2-Feb-20|     2020-02-02|
|02-Feb-20|     2020-02-02|
+---------+---------------+
```