# How to convert string in DataFrame to date in pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark

I would like to convert string in a column of DataFrame to date in pyspark.

```
l = [("10/14/2000","12/4/1991","5/8/1991"), ("11/3/1391","1/26/1992","9/5/1992")]
spark.createDataFrame(l).collect()
df = spark.createDataFrame(l, ["first", 'second',"third"])

df2 = df.select(col("first"),to_date(col("first"),"MM/dd/yyyy").alias("date"))
df3 = df.select(col("first"),to_date(col("first"),"%M/%d/%y").alias("date"))
```

I tried those codes above, but neither of them worked.

Could somebody help me to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code snippet you are using is correct , however the `date_format` you are using for parsing is not in line with `Spark 3.x`

Furthermore to handle inconsistent cases , like - 10/14/2000 and 11/3/1391 , with `MM/dd/yyyy` , you can set the `timeParserPolicy=LEGACY` as the below link is applicable for `Spark 3.x` , more info about this can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62602720/string-to-date-migration-from-spark-2-0-to-3-0-gives-fail-to-recognize-eee-mmm)

The available DateTime Patterns for Parsing can be found - https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-datetime-pattern.html

#### Data Prepartion

```
l = [("10/14/2000","12/4/1991","5/8/1991"), ("11/3/1391","1/26/1992","9/5/1992")]

df = sql.createDataFrame(l, ["first", 'second',"third"])

df.show()

+----------+---------+--------+
|     first|   second|   third|
+----------+---------+--------+
|10/14/2000|12/4/1991|5/8/1991|
| 11/3/1391|1/26/1992|9/5/1992|
+----------+---------+--------+
```

### To Date

```
df.select(F.col("first"),F.to_date(F.col("first"),"MM/dd/yyyy").alias("date")).show()

+----------+----------+
|     first|      date|
+----------+----------+
|10/14/2000|2000-10-14|
| 11/3/1391|1391-11-03|
+----------+----------+
```

Comment: I solved the issue, thank you so much.